# How to not execute jobs which are past their scheduled time

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I observed that jobs which are normally scheduled at midnight (but could not be executed because the server went into energy saving mode) get executed after the server comes out of energy saving mode. This leads to unexpected execution times.

Is there a way to tell Quartz to not execute jobs after they are too far behind their target time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You just need to tell Quartz what to do about [job misfires](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-04.html#TutorialLesson4-MisfireInstructions):

> Another important property of a Trigger is its “misfire instruction”. A misfire occurs if a persistent trigger “misses” its firing time because of the scheduler being shutdown, or because there are no available threads in Quartz’s thread pool for executing the job. The different trigger types have different misfire instructions available to them. By default they use a ‘smart policy’ instruction - which has dynamic behavior based on trigger type and configuration. When the scheduler starts, it searches for any persistent triggers that have misfired, and it then updates each of them based on their individually configured misfire instructions. When you start using Quartz in your own projects, you should make yourself familiar with the misfire instructions that are defined on the given trigger types, and explained in their JavaDoc.

The specific misfire instruction depends on the `Trigger` type you're using. For a daily job It could be something like this:

```
trigger = newTrigger()
        .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(0,0)
                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()) // set misfire instruction
        .build();
```

But again, it depends on the type of trigger. Just use your IDE to see what `withMisfire*()` methods are available, and use either `withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing` or `withMisfireHandlingInstructionNextWithRemainingCount` (both will ignore the missed execution and wait for the next scheduled one).

When I had to learn about the different types of misfire instructions, besides Quartz's tutorials and API documentation, I used [this blog entry](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-misfire-instructions.html).

Comment: Thanks! I use CronTrigger like this `TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronSchedule).withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing()).build();`. I'll see if that fixes my issues but I'm confident.

Comment: @MartinFernau How did it go?

Comment: looks great. Today tests shows that the jobs are not executed any more. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinFernau Glad I could help :)